Coordinate difference when exporting .shp to .dxf?
I'm working with both QGIS and AutoCAD. I import DXF files into QGIS, where I then digitize some geometries and then I export them back to .DXF to be able to upload them on the company's internal platform.
The thing is, when I export it to .DXF, the coordinates change very very slightly and I don't know why.
I tested this by having some geometries in a DXF file then importing them to QGIS and exporting them to DXF again without changing anything. I used the difference option in QGIS and the geometries outlines were highlighted. The difference is very very small but I don't get why it's happening. Help please?

Can you please provide some more information. How do you import the dxf in QGIS (with or without a plugin?) and which CRS do you use in QGIS?

Shapefiles store their coordinates as double precision https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format , DXF files store their coordinates as a text string up to 16 decimal places https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-D4242737-58BB-47A5-9B0E-1E3DE7E7D647 there will be some coordinate rounding.

Yes, sorry. I just drag and drop the DXF, edit what I need to edit and then use the "Export Project to DXF" from "Project", so no plugin. The CRS is EPSG:3844 - Pulkovo 1942(58) / Stereo 70

@MichaelStimson thank you for letting me know! so it seems like there's no solution for this?

Correct, there is just a difference in how the two systems record coordinates, when the coordinates are converted the digits that can't be stored are discarded. I've seen similar happen when data is projected, edited, and then projected again multiple times.

@MichaelStimson The main issue is that in our platform we "associate" a geometry with some information about it. When the geometry changes, it resets and it's no longer associated with anything. Can the dev just make the level of change in coordinates higher for the geometry to be reset? Now it's set to the 5th decimal. If it changes, it's reset (so from 70.00000 to 70.00001). Otherwise it's too small of a change. So we need to make it less restrictive. What do you think? I hope I'm being clear

The link must be tenuous indeed for such a minor change to be disastorous; GIS is fundamentally a geometry with some information but what you're contending with here is a fundamental concept with the storage formats DXF https://damassets.autodesk.net/content/dam/autodesk/www/developer-network/platform-technologies/autocad-dxf-archive/acad_r12_dxf.pdf as text and Esri Shapefile as double precision (binary) https://www.esri.com/content/dam/esrisites/sitecore-archive/Files/Pdfs/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf the only possible scope for devs is to make the link more robust.

@MichaelStimson I understand. Thank you so much for the explanation! It helped me a lot

In my tests, i noticed that rounding differences occur when exporting via the context menu of the layer. when using the ‘native:dxfexport’ algorithm, all decimal places were exported correctly. I temporarily saved the data as a geopackage for processing in the GIS.

@Kasluk24 That's interesting! You wrote a script in Python to do this, right? It'd be great if it worked this way, I can just create a small plugin for it

@Maria I did not do it with a python script, but via the algorithm toolbox of QGIS, but as a script would of course also be possible. It is also important that the data is never stored temporarily in a format that does not support so many decimal places.

@Maria, you wrote in a comment that you import the DXF file by dragging and dropping it in QGIS and then you edit it. Anyway it is not possible to directly edit a DXF layer imported by drag & drop in QGIS. Moreover, you mentioned exporting .shp to .dxf in the title, but there is no mention of .shp in the description. What do the .shp files have to do with the question? What is exactly your procedure? Please update your question with detailed information.

@MichaelStimson, "up to 16 decimal places" at https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2024/ENU/?guid=GUID-D4242737-58BB-47A5-9B0E-1E3DE7E7D647 probably actually means "up to 16 significant figures".
